# Shopify: get current logged in user ID in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify

I'm trying to build an app for shopify and I'm interested if I can get the current logged user ID using javascript api or something similar.
I was looking at the ajax api: http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api and I can see you can get the current products that the current user has added to his shopping cart, but nothing about the user ID.

Is it possible, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet would be to create an App that installs a simple ScriptTag in the shop. That script can then report the customer ID back to the App securely. Very simple to do that. Forget the front-end API as there is no secure way to call your App using that.

Comment: sounds interesting. but how do you get the customer ID using the script? that's what I'm looking for

Comment: use Liquid. 

    var id = {{ customer.id}};
    // do some callback to my secure App Proxy now with id

Comment: Script tags can't use Liquid. I can't a reference in the Shopify docs, though it makes sense that they can't. Some useful info on https://nozzlegear.com/blog/the-developers-guide-to-shopify-script-tags

Answer (score 20):

You can try `__st.cid` in JavaScript for getting customer id.

Comment: This works for me. It is undefined if the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 18):

I've found the `__st` variables unreliable (`__st_uniqToken` for one).
I believe the proper way to do this in Javascript is using the following call:

`ShopifyAnalytics.lib.user().id()`

You can also get the unique user id (non-logged in id) with:

`ShopifyAnalytics.lib.user().properties().uniqToken`

This is also the only reliable way to get it on the checkout page. I previously used `__st_uniqToken`, but it has since stopped working.

**NOTE** This is no longer 100% fool-proof. Shopify have **AGAIN** changed how their site works on the landing and thank-you pages.
I've had to resort to the following function to get a user id 'reliably'.

```
var user_id = function() {
    try {
        return ShopifyAnalytics.lib.user().id();
    } catch(e) {}
    try {
        return ShopifyAnalytics.lib.user().properties().uniqToken;
    } catch(e) {}
    try {
        return ShopifyAnalytics.lib.user().anonymousId();
    } catch(e) {}
    return __st_uniqToken;
};
```

Developing for Shopify is a true nightmare. I spend 50% of my time un-breaking my product every few weeks because them.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it actually answers the question "get current logged in user ID".

Comment: The `ShopifyAnalytics.lib.user()` object appears to have changed since this answer. I'm now seeing only the `traits`  function, with property uniqToken, i.e. `ShopifyAnalytics.lib.user.traits().uniqToken`

Comment: @AndyTriggs now it's `ShopifyAnalytics.lib.user().traits().uniqToken`

Answer (score 10):

In *layout.liquid* file you can add this code to define global **customerId** variable

```
{% if customer %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
   window.customerId = "{{ customer.id }}";   
  </script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It will only work if you are using it in .liquid file. It will not work in .js file.

Comment: This is the way how to declare a GLOBAL variable in .liquid file which will be accessible from any js file.

Comment: This solution might be OK for private apps, but to expect merchants to edit a liquid template to allow access to a customer ID for public apps on the frontend is hacky at best. Nothing against you Tim, just frustrated with this answer because Shopify staff are also recommending this approach which is totally anti-shop friendly and anti-good experience.

Comment: For sure I'm not really satisfied with this variant of it but as you said the other variants and even official if really hard to identify as better. So declaring something that is more reliable is better. But yeah I did it in my own theme for my own functionality.

Comment: @TimKozak What is the best way to add this snippet to the layout file using the Admin Assets API?

Answer (score 10):

Just get it from `ShopifyAnalytics.meta.page.customerId` is your script

Comment: Or to be more specific

var customer_id = meta.page.customerId;

Comment: `ShopifyAnalytics.meta.page` object doesn't contain `customerId` anymore

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Shopify API was again changed, I see that now the user Id is in `ShopifyAnalytics.lib.user().traits().uniqToken`. Also, it may take time for this value to be loaded.

I use this code snippet to perform the job once the value available.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  actOnUser = function(retry, func){
    if (ShopifyAnalytics && ShopifyAnalytics.lib && ShopifyAnalytics.lib.user) {
      console.log(ShopifyAnalytics.lib.user().traits().uniqToken); // Do your work here.
    } else {
      if (retry > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          func(retry - 1, func);
        }, 1000);
      }
      console.log('User not ready'); // Can be removed - just for debug
    }
  }
  console.log('Starting');
  setTimeout(function() {
    actOnUser(10, actOnUser);
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution is not 100% about getting `user_id`, but about detecting if current user is logged in as admin. You can use `typeof Shopify.AdminBar` to check if the admin bar exists. It's automatically created by Shopify if the current user is admin. Maybe this will help someone.